# How to call a inherited function inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, callback, peerjs

I have a quick question. I am making video chat with peerjs and I get the error that function is undefined. Here is the code:

Main constructor is Voip which is called in other file like

```
var voip = new Voip();
```

This is the function:

```
function Voip(options) {
var self = this;

options = options ||  {};

var allOptions = _.extend({
secure: true,
debug: 3
}, options);

this.peerjs = new Peer(allOptions);
```

First problem is here. How could I call otherCall inside callback function with listening to call event Function otherCall is at the bottom. Now it's written with this.otherCall but that doesn't work. I would just like to go to this function whenever I receive call event and answer the call.

```
this.peerjs.on('call', function(call){
call.answer(window.localStream);
this.otherCall(call);
  });
}
```

And then the Voip is extended with inheriting EventEmitter. Could I get rid of this line completely and still maintain same functionality? I don't use EventEmitter at all but was used in code I helped with.

```
Voip.prototype = _.extend(EventEmitter.prototype, {
```

And same here, self.otherCall doesn't work. What is the solution?

```
callOther: function(receiverId) {
var self = this;
var call = self.peerjs.call(receiverId, window.localStream);
self.otherCall(call);
},

otherCall: function(call) {

if (window.existingCall) {
    window.existingCall.close();
  }

call.on('stream', function(stream){
$('iframe').putthecodein....(stream)
  });
  window.existingCall = call;
}
});
```

Hope I've been clear in my question. If I summarize I want to call function otherCall once when listening to call event and second time inside callOther function. And for inheriting EventEmitter I wonder if I can modify code in such way that I don't need that line and everything still works.

Comment: In your `call` event, does your `otherCall` line throw error? Same question for the `callOther` function. Have you tried logging what `this` is inside `call` event, and what `self` is inside `callOther` function. It could be a scope issue.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Yes `otherCall` cannot be called in both cases in that line. Also `self` inside `callOther` is Voip object and `this` inside call event is undefined.

Comment: Is your `otherCall` function defined in the `Voip` object or is it just a global function?

Comment: It's inside this one `Voip.prototype = _.extend(EventEmitter.prototype, {` that's why I asked if I could get rid of this extend and inheritance and how. Cause in that case I would be able to call this function as it would be inside Voip.

Comment: Is it possible somehow for you to create a jsFiddle of it?

Comment: Unfortunately no cause we use our own peerjs server so things are little bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this. It might work.

```
var self = this;

self.peerjs.on('call', function(call){
    call.answer(window.localStream);
    self.otherCall.call(self, call);
});
```

Comment: It does work, calls the function but then I have problem on this line `call.on('stream', function(stream)` inside `otherCall` function. It says it cannot read property `on` of undefined.

Comment: Problem was in not receiving the stream in the right moment. That function was called before the stream was even on.